# VIPER Entities and where to store 'em

Tags: ios, swift, viewmodel, clean-architecture, viper-architecture

So, I am currently refactoring a really large project to VIPER architecture and most of its module's views are UITableViews. I discovered almost every topic on the internet about VIPER and UITableView, but one thing remains unclear: where should I store ViewModel and do I really need them?

For example, I have simple VIPER module with UITableViewController and I need to present list of items. Interactor fetches JSON with array of some items which I decode to Codable structs. Then I push array of this structs from interactor back to presenter via InteractorOutput protocol. And now I have two questions:

1. Do I have to use another data model (ViewModel) to show data in view, or can I go with already existing Codable Struct?
2. Where should I store my ViewModels? Inside Presenter and ask for the data from the View like this: presenter.getData(forItemAt: indexPath.row). Or I have to push array of ViewModels to View and ask View to show them?

Comment: IMO, I would use ViewModel not Codable Struct. Codable can be passed to Presenter to transform into ViewModel, then from View you will ask Presenter.

Answer (score 1):

As described in https://TheSwiftDev.com/the-ultimate-viper-architecture-tutorial,

- The UITableView is quarantined within the view zone.
- There are no view models per se.  That purpose of other architectures is carved up differently in VIPER, mainly in the presenter zone but without overt knowledge of the view itself (instead focusing on the business-rules of the use-case).  A UI-view in the VIPER view zone conforms to at least one use-case.  The data flowing from interactor zone (acquisition/storage) through presenter zone (business/app-domain rule-enforcement/processing) to view zone (and vice versa) is modeled without direct knowledge of the specific OS's specific UI constructs & their parameter needs.  When crossing VIPER zones, the entities are modeled as if portable (even if not yet) to other UIs on other OSes.  For example, when developing for iOS/iPadOS/WatchOS apps, the interzone exchange of events & data/entities is done so that they are at least agnostic of the peculiarities of iOS/iPadOS/WatchOS UI view constructs & parameters thereof so that the 4 VIPER zones other than view & router {interactor, presenter, entities} remain unchanged in a MacOS version of the same app.  With care (e.g., Swift on all non-Apple platforms; OpenCombine framework instead of Apple Combine framework for interzone effect-reactive dataflow) this concept can be extrapolated to Android & UWP version of the app as well, but the Apple-centric portions of interactor zone would need to change as well, which is the reason for quarantining each topic compartmentalized in a zone so that it does not contaminate other zones (as seen is Massive View Controller architecture).
- The presenter zone should have no knowledge of or access to UITableView constructs at all.  Hence, presenter.getData(forItemAt: indexPath.row) would be replaced with the presenter working on a collection of entities where the collection of entities might get UI-viewed in view zone as a UITableView on iOS/iPadOS/WatchOS but get UI-viewed quite differently on MacOS or Android or UWP, perhaps not as a table at all, but rather as a 2D array of icons/choices to router to navigate.  Your “Or [do] I [need to] have to push array of ViewModels to View and ask View to show them?” is nearly hitting the nail on the head, except that VIPER architecture does not use the term ViewModel there; use the word entity instead (i.e., purely app-domain entities divorced from UI and from OS).
- Codable is an interface within Apple's JSON processing.  Hence, it would need to be quarantined within interactor zone for portability (real or anticipated-for-good-mental-hygiene) to nonApple OSes.  The input from (and output to) JSON interactor would need be expressed in entities that are purely app-domain without knowledge of a nonportable framework such as Codable in SwiftUI.  There would need to be a conversion from Apple-centric ways of representing JSON processing's output to the purely app-domain ways of representing those equivalent entities.